# IOException[Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors

Tags: elasticsearch-5, elastic4s

In Elasticsearch getting the following error.

RemoteTransportException[[CN8keD-][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[CN8keD-][127.0.0.1:9300] indices:data/write/update[s]]]; nested: MapperParsingException
IOException[Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and the problem was that my mapping was wrong.
I was trying to map a boolean field as integer.